# Hahn Decomposition $(P,P^c)$

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure with Hahn decomposition $(P,P^c)$. Show that $(-\mu)^+=\mu^-$ and $(-\mu)^-=\mu^+$ and that $(P^c,P)$ is a Hahn decomposition of $-\mu$

I would like to know the following would help me solve this exercise, and if so, how could I apply it:

$\mu^+(E):=\mu(E\cap P)\ge0$, and $\mu^-(E):=-\mu(E\cap P^c)\ge0$

Comment: Have you tried showing that $(P^{c},P)$ is a Hahn decomposition of $-\mu$?  I would start there.

Comment: The two definitions you wrote up will be definitely needed.

Comment: @PeterMorfe I haven't tried, I got stuck with the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $E \subseteq P$. By assumption $\mu(E) \geq 0$, so $ -\mu(E) \leq 0$.

Similarly, if $E \subseteq P^c$, then $-\mu(E) \geq 0$. So, $(P^c,P)$ decomposes $-\mu$.

Now, by the above, $(-\mu)^+(E) = -\mu(E \cap P^c) = \mu^-(E)$. And similarly $(-\mu)^- = \mu^+$.

Comment: Thank you very much it has helped me a lot